# How to find out how big the Monero blockchain is?

Tags: monerod

Is there any way we can find out how big the Monero blockchain download size is today? I see old threads dated 2018 which say it's around 50gb, but there must be a URL somewhere we can found out the current size of the blockchain if we wanted to download for setting up a new node.

*Thanks in advance for any help.*

Answer (score 1):

You can call a daemons RPC [get_info](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_info) method which will tell you the blockchain database size (in bytes) in the responses `database_size` field.

And you can find a public node on sites like https://moneroworld.com/.

For example:

```
curl -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_info"}' \
  http://node.moneroworld.com:18089/json_rpc
```

Response (truncated):

```
{
  "id": "0",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    ...
    "database_size": 85899345920,
    ...
  }
}
```

Which you then convert the bytes to GB however you prefer. The above shows roughly 85 GB. Note this is not the exact size of the blockchain, rather the current size of the database on the node queried.

Comment: And a pruned blockchain is roughly 1/3 of the full blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

GetBlkSize.sh

```
echo "" > /tmp/j
curl -s https://monero.fail/ | grep "<td>https" | sed -r 's/.*<td>(https.*)<\/td>.*/\1/g' | while read -r line ; do
    ./knockknock.sh $line &
done
wait
exit 0
```

knockknock.sh

```
    x=$(curl -sd '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_info"}' $1/json_rpc | grep 'database_size' |  sed -r 's/.*: ([0-9]*)\,.*/\1/g');
    y=$((x/1024/1024/1024));
    if [ "0" -ne "$y" ]; then
        echo -e "\t$y GB block chain at $1" >> /tmp/j 
    fi
    exit 0
```

then cat /tmp/j

Basically this script looks for the secure monero blockchains. Some are compressed and some are not. So you will see something like this:

```
$ cat /tmp/j

    140 GB block chain at https://chad.fiatfaucet.com
    140 GB block chain at https://xmr.moneromerch.com:18089
    50 GB block chain at https://xmr.voidnet.tech
    50 GB block chain at https://node.monerod.org
    140 GB block chain at https://monero1.heitechsoft.com:18081
    140 GB block chain at https://community.organic-meatballs.duckdns.org
    140 GB block chain at https://fallacy.fiatfaucet.com:18089
    140 GB block chain at https://community.organic-meatballs.duckdns.org:443
    50 GB block chain at https://kowalski.fiatfaucet.com
    50 GB block chain at https://dewitte.fiatfaucet.com
    140 GB block chain at https://xmrnode1.ditatompel.com:443
    140 GB block chain at https://xmrnode1.ditatompel.com
    140 GB block chain at https://node.xmr-alias.de:443
    140 GB block chain at https://xmr.zgabur.sk:18089
    50 GB block chain at https://xmr.lukas.services:443
```